# Maclaurin series for $\arccos(x)$ via integral of $-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to expand the series for $\arccos(x)$. So far I have obtained successfully the series for $\arcsin(x)$ and $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}}$

The integral of $-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}}=-1-\dfrac{x^2}{2}-\dfrac{3}{8}x^4-\dfrac{5}{16}x^6-...$

I know that I can integrate terms by terms but I don't know how to get the $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Wolfram gives the series expansion as:
$\arccos(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}-\dfrac{3x^5}{40}...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\arcsin x + \arccos x =\frac\pi2$$

and

$$\arcsin x =\int_0^x\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}= x+\dfrac{1}{6}x^3+\dfrac{3}{40}x^5...$$

Edit: Responding to question in comments below.

Integrate $\arccos$ function directly,

$$\int_0^x d(\arccos t) =\arccos x - \arccos(0) =-\int_0^x\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

Then use $\arccos(0)=\frac\pi2$ to arrive,

$$\arccos x =\frac\pi2 -\int_0^x\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

Comment: If I decide to use the series for $-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ without employing the above identity, how can I make the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ appear?

Comment: @JamesWarthington - See the added in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Your identity is the fastest way to compute the series without much labor, thanks!

Comment: @JamesWarthington - You're welcome.