# Maclaurin series for $\operatorname {arccosh}(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Maclaurin series for $\operatorname {arccosh}(x)$

I have asked about the series expansion for $\arccos(x)$here:
[Maclaurin series for $\arccos(x)$ via integral of $-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3422385/maclaurin-series-for-arccosx-via-integral-of-dfrac1-sqrt1-x2/3422388?noredirect=1#comment7038195_3422388)

Is there an identity such as:
$\operatorname {arcsinh}(x)+\operatorname {arccosh}(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$?

If the series for $\arccos(x)$ is

$\arccos(x)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x-\dfrac{x^3}{6}-\dfrac{3x^5}{40}...$

Then the series for $\operatorname {arccosh}(x)$ is:

$\operatorname {arccosh}(x)= \dfrac{\pi}{2}-x+\dfrac{x^3}{6}-\dfrac{3x^5}{40}...$

Is this a correct guess?

Comment: It is a "good" guess, but wrong.  Note $\text{arccosh}(0) = i\pi/2$ is not real, since $\cosh(x) \ge 1$ for all real $x$.

Comment: So does this series have a Maclaurin expansion or not? Do you mean it only has a Laurent series?

Comment: It has no *real* Maclaurin series.  It certainly has a power series expansion at $0 + 0\mathrm{i}$.

Comment: Can you expand it so I can learn?

Answer (score 2):

The function $\operatorname{arccosh}$ is not defined at $0$; its domain is $[1,\infty)$. Therefore, it has no MacLaurin series.

Comment: I have not learnt complex analysis yet, but can you show me how to develop this function into Laurent series?

Comment: Centered at what point?

Comment: At $0+0i$, is it feasible?

Comment: No. Since $\cosh'(0)=0$, $\cosh$ is not invertible in the neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: I have to consult Wolfram, and it says that the series expansion at 0 is $(-1)^{(arg(x))(2\pi)}(\dfrac{i\pi}{2}-ix-\dfrac{ix^3}{6}-\dfrac{3ix}{40}...)$ 

Is this answer wrong?

Comment: Because of that $\arg(x)$ in there, this is not a Laurent series.

Comment: So is it a Taylor series?

Comment: Maybe, but the Taylor series of *what*? I don't know.

Comment: So it is not a series representation of $\arccosh(x)$?

Comment: In order that that is a meaningful question, you must answer this question first: what **is** $\operatorname{arccosh}(x)$?

Comment: Ok I see, thank you.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.